# apache2: subdirectory won't work if I enable app at /

Tags: apache, gitlab

I built a personal server at home which is hosted at, let's say, `example.org` and I installed `GitLab` as a subdirectory so I can access to it at `example.org/gitlab`. As GitLab is the only one application I have so far, everything works smoothly.

Now I want to have a blog at root, so I enabled Apache default site to do some tests. I can see apache2 default page at `example.org` (which is where I want my blog) but GitLab won't work anymore at `example.org/gitlab`. All I have is a "page not found". `GitLab` will only work if I disable the default page at `/`.

I tried using Alias, I also read something about redirections but I haven't managed to make `example.org` and `example.org/gitlab` work together so far.

Any advice about where to look, please?

Answer (score 0):

If you generate two virtualhosts both must have different ServerName, otherwise first match receives all requests and second virtualhost will be ignored.